# How to hide available fields from list view?

Tags: list-view

I'm working in list view where I want to hide some custom fields from the available fields in list view.
In the below picture I have highlighted on a field that I want to hide from the list view. So can someone tell me how to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: But you want to leave the ability of the user intact to view these fields in record pages and elsewhere,  right?! What has this to do with Apex, sfdx, salesforce1-app?

Comment: I just dont want to show the user Phone number field in the list view. But I want that field on other purpose ... so I cant user Field level security to the user

Comment: that is not possible, unless you develop your own custom list view component.

Comment: @GuyClairbois, maybe add this as the answer?!

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that is not possible, unless you develop your own custom list view component.